# Is it always faster to use copy instead of append on a slice?

Tags: go

When doing an iterative grow on a slice, it's easy to see why allocating the size first (if known) is more efficient than using the append function, since the latter will be deciding, on each iteration, on whether to increase the slice capacity. But I'm curious to know if, when concatenating two large slices in a non-iterative way, using the variadic form of append would be any less efficient than using a make/copy construct. For instance (assuming sl1 and sl2 are of type []int)

```
sl = append(sl, sl2...)
```

versus

```
nsl = make([]int, len(sl) + len(sl2))
i := copy(nsl, sl)
copy(nsl[i], sl2)
sl = nsl
```

I would have thought the first form (which is much more readable) could still be efficient since I expect there is still only one capacity change (based on the number of arguments to the append call). Am I thinking about this right?

Comment: Benchmark it, if you actually want to know.

Comment: It should be self-evident that it cannot be "always" faster. A call to `append` *may* not allocate, while the `copy` code you've produced definitely *always* allocates. It's not clear why you think your copy can can *ever* be faster, unless you have benchmarks showing that it can be. You should certainly not be using your `copy` code instead of a simple call to `append` in the general case.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not great with benchmarking yet so I thought those in the know might be able to answer. And to be clear, what I'm asking is whether using append in the variadic form would grow the slice in one hit or would it effectively iterate until all individual elements are added (which would be slower than the copy).

Comment: That's not really any more clear, `append` is always variadic, there is no alternate form. Why would `append` be implemented in such a way as to allocate as inefficiently as possible? It knows exactly how many elements must be appended, so there's one check for capacity and then extend the array only if necessary.

Comment: Ok good point. I just see a lot of cases where people have resorted to setting known adequate-capacity slice before assigning the elements, but always in the context of an iterative problem. But you're right - it would be very poor form if go did not consider all of the arguments (for append) before growing the slice as required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append` and `copy` use the same underlying copy primitive.

`append` will not allocate memory if there's sufficient capacity in the destination slice.

The `append` code is easier to read.

Comment: Great, thank you!